# Speeding up mass to the speed of light

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Suppose you have mass of 1kg as you start to move it at a speed which is 90% of the speed of light then what will happen to that mass? Will it increase?

Comment: Yes and no. Depending on your definition of mass. There are two different schools of thought here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a controversy on whether mass increases with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133376/why-is-there-a-controversy-on-whether-mass-increases-with-speed)